# Maven Java Version Configuration ignored by Eclipse/Idea

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, maven-compiler-plugin

I have:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.1</version>
           <configuration>
              <source>1.6</source>
              <target>1.6</target>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Yet I have no problem declaring:

```
public enum DirectoryWatchService {

    INSTANCE;

    private java.util.Optional<String> test;
    private java.nio.file.Files files;
}
```

Eclipse doesn't bother. IntelliJ neither. Even Maven does not bother. 
I can even do a *mvn clean package*. Builds the darn thing without any warning whatsoever.

Comment: Remove `<pluginManagement>` and you'll see errors as high as the sky.

Comment: in general, source/target are often misunderstood, they check against syntax, not API used. you should always use the [bootstrap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) option to make sure to compile and be consistent with your target java version. Alternatively, the animal-sniffer maven plugin is the way to go to break the build if you use java 7/8 API while compiling with target 6

Comment: Furthermore you should use toolchain to correctly define the used JDK independent of the JDK which is used to run Maven itself...

Comment: @Tunaki: Sadly, no. I do not.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are hitting the cross compilation misunderstanding of `source`/`target` options. Using a major version in your classpath (JDK 7 or 8) but wishing to compile against a minor version (6 in your case).
Compilation will be fine, but the you will have errors at **runtime** (i.e. [`NoClassDefFoundError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) or [`NoSuchMethodError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html), probably also the more generic [`LinkageError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/LinkageError.html)).

Using [`source`/`target`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#options), the Java compiler can be used as a cross-compiler to produce class files runnable on JDKs implementing an earlier version of the Java SE specification.

The common belief is that using two compiler options would be enough. However, The `source` option specifies against which version we are compiling while the `target` option specifies the lowest Java version to support.

The compiler works on bytecode generation and `source` and `target` are used to generate compatible bytecode during cross-compilation. However, Java API are not handled by the compiler (they are provided as part of the JDK installation, the famous `rt.jar` file). The compiler doesn’t have any knowledge of API, it just compiles against the current `rt.jar`. Hence, when compiling with `target=1.6` using JDK 1.7, the compiler will still point to the JDK 7 `rt.jar`.

**So, how can we actually have a correct cross-compilation?**

[Since JDK 7, javac prints a warning](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/bootclasspath_older_source) in case of `source`/`target` not in combination with the `bootclasspath` option. The `bootclasspath` option is the key option in these cases to point to the `rt.jar` of the desired target Java version (hence, you need to have the target JDK installed in your machine). As such, `javac` will effectively compile against the good Java API.

**But that may still not be enough!**

Not all Java API comes from the `rt.jar`. Other classes are provided by the `lib\ext` folder. A further `javac` option is used for that, `extdirs`. From official Oracle docs

> If you are cross-compiling (compiling classes against bootstrap and extension classes of a different Java platform implementation), this option specifies the directories that contain the extension classes.

Hence, even using `source`/`target` and `bootclasspath` options, we may still miss something during cross-compilation, as also explained in the [official example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#crosscomp-example) which comes with the javac documentation.

> The Java Platform JDK's javac would also by default compile against its own bootstrap classes, so we need to tell javac to compile against JDK 1.5 bootstrap classes instead. We do this with -bootclasspath and -extdirs. Failing to do this might allow compilation against a Java Platform API that would not be present on a 1.5 VM and would fail at runtime.

**But.. it may still not be enough!**

From Oracle official [documentation](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/how_to_cross_compile_for)

> Even when the bootclasspath and -source/-target are all set appropriately for cross-compilation, compiler-internal contracts, such as how anonymous inner classes are compiled, may differ between, say, javac in JDK 1.4.2 and javac in JDK 6 running with the -target 1.4 option.

The solution suggested (from [Oracle official](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/how_to_cross_compile_for) documentation)

> The most reliably way to produce class files that will work on a particular JDK and later is to compile the source files using the oldest JDK of interest. Barring that, the bootclasspath must be set for robust cross-compilation to an older JDK.

**So, this is really not possible?**

[Spring 4 currently supports Java 6, 7 and 8](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/03/how-spring-achieves-compatibility-with-java-6-7-and-8). Even using Java 7 and Java 8 features and API. How can it then be compatible to Java 7 and 8?!

Spring makes use of `source`/`target` and `bootclasspath` flexibility. Spring 4 always compiles with `source`/`target` to Java 6 so that bytecode can still run under JRE 6. Hence no Java 7/8 language features are used: syntax keeps Java 6 level.
But it also uses Java 7 and Java 8 API! Hence, `bootclasspath` option is not used. Optional, Stream and many other Java 8 API are used. It then injects beans depending on Java 7 or Java 8 API only when JRE 7/8 are detected at runtime: smart approach!

**But how does Spring assure API compatibility then?**

Using the [Maven Animal Sniffer](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) plugin.
This plugin checks whether your application is API compatible with a specified Java version. Is called animal sniffer because Sun traditionally named the different versions of Java after [different animals](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/codenames-136090.html) (Java 4 = Merlin (bird), Java 5 = Tiger, Java 6 = Mustang (horse), Java 7 = Dolphin, Java 8 = no animal).

You can add the following to your POM file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
        <configuration>
          <signature>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
            <artifactId>java16</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
          </signature>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>ensure-java-1.6-class-library</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the build will fail as soon as you use JDK 7 API while wishing to use only JDK 6 API.

This usage is also recommended in the official [`source`/`target` page of the `maven-compiler-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

> **Note**: Merely setting the `target` option does not guarantee that your code actually runs on a JRE with the specified version. The pitfall is unintended usage of APIs that only exist in later JREs which would make your code fail at runtime with a linkage error. To avoid this issue, you can either configure the compiler's boot classpath to match the target JRE or use the Animal Sniffer Maven Plugin to verify your code doesn't use unintended APIs.

---

**Java 9 Update**
In Java 9 this mechanism [has been radically changed](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/resource/JavaOne/J1_2016-jdk9-lang-tools-libs.pdf) to the following approach:

```
javac --release N ...
```

Will be semantically equivalent to

```
javac -source N -target N -bootclasspath rtN.jar ...
```

> - Information about APIs of earlier releases available to `javac`
>
>   - Stored in a compressed fashion
>   - Only provide Java SE *N* and JDK *N*-exported APIs that are platform neutral
> - Same set of release values *N* as for `-source` / `-target`
> - Incompatible combinations of options rejected

Main advantages of the `--release N` approach:

> - No user need to manage artifacts storing old API information
> - Should remove need to use tools like the Maven plugin Animal Sniffer
> - May use newer compilation idioms than the `javac` in older releases
>
>   - Bug fixes
>   - Speed improvements

---

**Update on Java 9 and Maven**
Since version `3.6.0`, the `maven-compiler-plugin` provides support for Java 9 via its [`release`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#release) option:

> The `-release` argument for the Java compiler, supported since Java9

An example:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>8</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explaination. I'll give the mentioned animal plugin a try.

Comment: A couple small comments on this answer. The `-source` option controls the *language level* of the source code accepted by the compiler. The `-target` option controls the *classfile version* emitted by the compiler. It may seem like they're independent, but they're really not; the dependency can be quite complicated. For example, compiling a lambda requires the `invokedynamic` bytecode, so `-source 1.8 -target 1.6` simply won't work.

Comment: The emphasis on library APIs is well on point. Certain language features, such as *try-with-resources*, require particular library APIs such as `AutoCloseable`. Thus, `-source 1.7 -target 1.6` might produce a valid 1.6 class file, but it won't be runnable on JDK 6.  The answer here is quite correct in saying that `-source x -target x` is insufficient to cross-compile to an earlier JDK version. It's very important to pay attention to the library API issues as well.

Comment: @StuartMarks thanks for your contribution, really appreciated! I suppose some of these assumptions [will change with Java 9](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/182) (especially the `bootclasspath` option referring to the disappearing `rt.jar`) and its modularization

Comment: Quite correct, there will be changes in Java 9. See also [JEP 247](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/247) which introduces a new `-release` option to replace the older options. Not yet final, still subject to change, etc.

Comment: I might be late to answer, but maven also provide the toolchain : this allow you to use a JDK8 to execute maven and a JDK6 to compile. And in a sense, that way better than using source/target: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html

Comment: Perfect answer. Exactly what I was looking for. Particularly differentiating between source/target, and APIs. If I could I would upvote many times again.