# How to make Maven 3.2.5 understand Java 6 project on a machine using Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

My machine has Java 1.7 installed:

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)

>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_80
```

I have a Java 1.6 project I want to run, however when I go to build this project I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/maven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getMainClass(Launcher.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:266)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

I previously had Maven 3.3.9 installed, and I read somewhere Maven 3.2.5 was the last version of Maven to support Java 6, so I removed Maven 3.3.9 and installed Maven 3.2.5

```
>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T09:29:23-08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.5
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

However when I go to build this 1.6 project, I still get the same major.minor version 51 exception thrown at me?

Any idea what's going on here? Any help or support would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: Error message is that byte code is Java 7.  This mean that the JVM you use is older than Java 7 which for OS X most likely is the Apple Java 6 version.   I would suggest reinstalling the JDK.

Comment: @ArunavSanyal You have misunderstood the question.

Comment: But JAVA_HOME is set to 7?

Answer (score 1):

How can this be a 1.6 project if you're compiling it using JDK 1.7? The fact you're not using the new language features available in Java 7 does not imply you're producing bytecode targeting Java 6 VM's.

The solution would be to install the latest version of Maven and build your project as usual. If you want to target previous 1.6 VM's then set the `source` and `target` variables to `1.6` in the [compiler](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) plugin.

Comment: Yes, I'm using that plugin to ensure my project is Java 6. But I think you're misunderstanding my question. My project is already Java 6, that's not an issue here. Read Thorbjørn's comment, you'll see my problem. But luckily I have a solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Seems like it's the day of cross compilation, also check [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913775/maven-java-version-configuration-ignored-by-eclipse-idea)

Comment: @arabian_albert I'm glad you found a fix for it. All the best. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

I'm running Eclipse Mars 4.5.1, Java EE

**Eclipse > Preferences > Installed JREs**

> Remove/Delete Java 1.6

**Eclipse > Preferences > Installed JREs > Execution Environment**

> Under the Execution Environment Pane, Select JAVASE-1.6 and in the
>   next Pane, check mark 1.6 Java. Repeat same steps for 1.7 (if you have
>   Java 7 installed, under 1.7 it should say 'perfect match')

Thanks Thorbjørn for pointing me in the right direction