# Pass JVM args to maven surefire, conditional on build Java version?

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

Is there a way that I can pass this `argLine` configuration to the maven-surefire plugin ONLY when `<jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>` is configured for Java **1.7**  but NOT when a user changes the `pom.xml` to be configured for java **1.8**?

The reason being that Java **1.8** doesn't have permgen space.

```
<argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Maven profile activation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) based on properties value, in this case the property will be `jdk.version` and its value the different configuration of JDK. The profile will then change the Maven Surefire Plugin configuration accordingly.

Hence, your pom may look like the following:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>surefire-java7</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>jdk.version</name>
                    <value>1.7</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>surefire-java8</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>jdk.version</name>
                    <value>1.8</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Note the `profiles` section at the end. Two profiles are defined:

- `surefire-java7`: it will be activated by the value `1.7` for the `jdk.version` variable and set the `argLine` for the Maven Surefire Plugin with the desired value
- `surefire-java8`: it will be activated by the value `1.8` for the `jdk.version` variable and set a different `argLine` for the Maven Surefire Plugin.

Also note that with this configuration you can even switch JDK version (and as such Surefire configuration) at demand from the command line, as following:

```
mvn clean test -Djdk.version=1.8
```

The associated profile will be automatically activated as part of the build.

---

Important note about cross-compilation (you may already be aware of it, but just in case) I would suggest to carefully read [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913775/maven-java-version-configuration-ignored-by-eclipse-idea).

Answer (score 6):

Rather than a property, you should use the JDK based activation.

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>surefire-java7</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>(,1.8)</jdk>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>surefire-java8</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>1.8</jdk>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.19.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Cf maven documentation.
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html
http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html