# Maven build how to use rt.jar which in java version 1.6 or before

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

I have legacy source which uses `new FtpClient()`, and found that `FtpClient` is a abstract class in jre1.7. The code is fine for jre1.6 or before.

I am using maven to build my project now. My `JAVA_HOME` points to jdk1.7, which cause the compilation of my source failure. But it is fine when my `JAVA_HOME` point to jdk1.6.  However, the jdk versioin in my company is 1.7 default, and would not downgrade to version 1.6.

**Question**: how to make it work to compile my source without change the `JAVA_HOME`?

Below the concerned build log:

```
[INFO] Compiling 601 source files to C:\MyData\Project\A-Trunk\CCA\Online\branches\CCA_TabletAccess_Maven\Common_Source\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

C:\MyData\Project\A-Trunk\CCA\Online\branches\CCA_TabletAccess_Maven\Common_Source\src\com\hhbb\cca\services\ens\util\FTPCommon.java:[44,9] error: FtpClient is abstract; cannot be instantiated

C:\MyData\Project\A-Trunk\CCA\Online\branches\CCA_TabletAccess_Maven\Common_Source\src\com\hhbb\cca\services\ens\util\FTPCommon.java:[45,6] error: cannot find symbol

could not parse error message:   symbol:   method openServer(String)
  location: variable aftp of type FtpClient
C:\MyData\Project\A-Trunk\CCA\Online\branches\CCA_TabletAccess_Maven\Common_Source\src\com\hhbb\cca\services\ens\util\FTPCommon.java:46: error: no suitable method found for login(String,String)
                aftp.login(user,psw);
                    ^

could not parse error message:     method FtpClient.login(String,char[],String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method FtpClient.login(String,char[]) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to char[] by method invocation conversion)
C:\MyData\Project\A-Trunk\CCA\Online\branches\CCA_TabletAccess_Maven\Common_Source\src\com\hhbb\cca\services\ens\util\FTPCommon.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
                aftp.ascii();
                    ^

could not parse error message:   symbol:   method ascii()
  location: variable aftp of type FtpClient
C:\MyData\Project\A-Trunk\CCA\Online\branches\CCA_TabletAccess_Maven\Common_Source\src\com\hhbb\cca\services\ens\util\FTPCommon.java:53: error: FtpClient is abstract; cannot be instantiated
                aftp = new FtpClient();
                       ^

C:\MyData\Project\A-Trunk\CCA\Online\branches\CCA_TabletAccess_Maven\Common_Source\src\com\hhbb\cca\services\ens\util\FTPCommon.java:[54,6] error: cannot find symbol

could not parse error message:   symbol:   method openServer(String,int)
  location: variable aftp of type FtpClient
C:\MyData\Project\A-Trunk\CCA\Online\branches\CCA_TabletAccess_Maven\Common_Source\src\com\hhbb\cca\services\ens\util\FTPCommon.java:55: error: no suitable method found for login(String,String)
                aftp.login(user,psw);
                    ^

could not parse error message:     method FtpClient.login(String,char[],String) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method FtpClient.login(String,char[]) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to char[] by method invocation conversion)
C:\MyData\Project\A-Trunk\CCA\Online\branches\CCA_TabletAccess_Maven\Common_Source\src\com\hhbb\cca\services\ens\util\FTPCommon.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
                aftp.binary();
                    ^

could not parse error message:   symbol:   method binary()
  location: variable aftp of type FtpClient
C:\MyData\Project\A-Trunk\CCA\Online\branches\CCA_TabletAccess_Maven\Common_Source\src\com\hhbb\cca\services\ens\util\FTPCommon.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
                  aftp.closeServer();
                      ^

could not parse error message:   symbol:   method closeServer()
  location: variable aftp of type FtpClient
C:\MyData\Project\A-Trunk\CCA\Online\branches\CCA_TabletAccess_Maven\Common_Source\src\com\hhbb\cca\services\ens\util\FTPCommon.java:127: error: cannot find symbol
                        aftp.cd(RWFileDir);
                            ^

could not parse error message:   symbol:   method cd(String)
  location: variable aftp of type FtpClient
C:\MyData\Project\A-Trunk\CCA\Online\branches\CCA_TabletAccess_Maven\Common_Source\src\com\hhbb\cca\services\ens\util\FTPCommon.java:128: error: cannot find symbol
                        TelnetOutputStream outs = aftp.put(filename);
                                                      ^


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 24 14:12:52 CST 2016
```

Comment: ```error: FtpClient is abstract; cannot be instantiated``` error with that code, this is not maven configuration or java language version problem

Comment: Fix the code or use Java 1.6. Should never have used a `sun.*` class in the first place.

Comment: @Evgeny Lebedev, But there is no error when I compile with jdk1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hitting a common misunderstanding of Java cross-compilation with a special case: you want to use `sun.*` classes, which have no guarantee to be compatible across Java versions. From [official Oracle note](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html)

> A Java program that directly calls into `sun.*` packages is not guaranteed to work on all Java-compatible platforms. In fact, such a program is not guaranteed to work even in future versions on the same platform.

In your specific case, setting `source`/`target` of the Maven Compiler Plugin would not be enough. And in general is really dangerous. The Java compiler only knows about bytecode, not about Java API (the `rt.jar` file). So compiling using Java 7 compiler would still use the `rt.jar` of Java 7, which in your case is going to break code for Java 6 (especially because of the `sun.*` usage).

Check [**this SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35915323/5606016) for a more in deep explanation on the matter. Check also comments from Stuart Marks from Oracle, if ever you have doubts about its content.

---

In your specific case, you hence **mandatory** need a JDK 6 installed, because you need to point to the JDK 6 `rt.jar` file for Java 6 API, otherwise your code would never compile correctly. For such, you could use the [`executable`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#executable) option of the Maven Compiler Plugin, to point at a different installation of JDK to use, in conjunction with the [`fork`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#fork) option.

However, you would have to do the same for test execution as well and in general for any plugin requiring this switch. Hence, a more reliable approach would be to set the `JAVA_HOME` variable upfront before every build (to point to JDK 6) or to use [Maven toolchain](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) and set a JDK to use across a set of Maven plugins. But, again, you need JDK 6 installed in your system, otherwise it would not work.

You may also consider [Maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to isolate the different JDK usage. In such a profile, I would also suggest to add the [Animal Sniffer Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) as described in the aforementioned SO answer.

---

As general consideration, the points above explain the why and how you could fix it temporarily, but your application and build may easily suffer maintenance headaches. A more structured approach is definitely to fix the usage of `sun.*` package, which is [a really bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834826/it-is-a-bad-practice-to-use-suns-proprietary-java-classes). But, yet again, even then be aware about cross-compilation, it's a tricky topic which is often underestimated.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to play with that:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: @Will do you have jdk 1.6 in your system ?

Comment: @Bhavesh, yes, I have. But please note that I don't expect set JAVA_HOME to that.

Comment: This won't work unless he both compiles and executes with a 1.6 JDK.

Comment: Have you tried to edit mvn.bat? You can override JAVA_HOME variable in that file

Comment: this solution won't work, check my answer, cross-compilation in this case is really dangerous and almost impossible because of the sun.* package usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the maven compiler plugin in the pom.xml file.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Play with different values of source and target here. You should get it.

Comment: not work... javac: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7